# Pulling file names from a list of full paths?

Tags: python, path-separator

I am trying to pull out file names from a specifically formatted document, and put them into a list.  The document contains a large amount of information, but the lines I am concerned about look like the following with "File Name: " always at the start of the line:

```
File Name: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

I tried the following:

```
xmlfile = open('my_file.xml', 'r')
filetext = xmlfile.read()
file_list = []
file_list.append(re.findall(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\.*(?=\n)', filetext))
```

This makes `file_list` look like:

```
[['File Name: c:\\windows\\system32\\file1.exe',
  'File Name: c:\\windows\\system32\\file2.exe',
  'File Name: c:\\windows\\system32\\file3.exe']]
```

I'm looking for my output to simply be:

```
(file1.exe, file2.exe, file3.exe)
```

I also tried using `ntpath.basename` on my above output, but it looks like it wants a string as input and not a list.

I'm very new to Python and scripting in general, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @P.J. If your file really is `xml`, there are python libraries to parse out xml fields (I think one is even jsut called `xml`; the one I'm slightly more familiar with is `lxml`). Then, inside the `os` module there's the `path` module which has `basename()` which will strip out what you want, and be more portable overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected output with following regular expression:

```
file_list = re.findall(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\([^\\]*)(?=\n)', filetext)
```

`([^\\]*)` will capture everything except a slash after final path separator until `\n` is encountered, see [online example](https://regex101.com/r/jE0dJ9/1). Since `findall` already returns a list there's no need to append the return value to existing list.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this up a bit to make it a bit clearer to read and separate the process a bit - clearly it can be done in one step, but I think your code is going to be tough to manage later

```
import re
import os

with open('my_file.xml', 'r') as xmlfile:
    filetext = xmlfile.read()   # this way the file handle goes away - you left the file open
file_list = []
my_pattern = re.compile(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\.*(?=\n)')
for filename in my_pattern.findall(filetext):
    cleaned_name = filename.split(os.sep)[-1]
    file_list.append(cleaned_name)
```

Comment: That worked great with my test data... although there was a missing ")" toward the end of the regex.  Once I added that in, all worked great!

Comment: Corrected, cut-n-paste issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a more *declarative* style. It ensures less bugs, high memory efficiency.

```
import os.path

pat = re.compile(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\.*(?=\n)')
with open('my_file.xml') as f:
    ms = (pat.match(line) for line in f)
    ns = (os.path.basename(m) for m in ms)
# the iterator ns emits names such as 'foo.txt'
for n in ns:
    # do something
```

If you change the regex slightly, i.e the grouping you don't even need `os.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. The reason `basename` wasn't working was because `re.findall()` returns a list which was being put into yet another list. Here's a fix for that which iterates through that list returned and creates another with just the base file names in:

```
import re
import os

with open('my_file.xml', 'rU') as xmlfile:
    file_text = xmlfile.read()
    file_list = [os.path.basename(fn)
                    for fn in re.findall(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\.*(?=\n)', file_text)]
```

Comment: This also worked great with my test data.  When I pull in my full document I am getting the following output:
['file1.exe&#13;&#13;', 'file2.exe&#13;&#13;', 'file3.exe&#13;&#13;']

Is there something I should do with the regex to prevent it from pulling the carriage return into the output?

Comment: I think the best thing to do might be to use [`open('my_file.xml', 'rU')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) which will convert the line endings (carriage-return, linefeed on Windows) read into single `\n` newline characters. The `'rU'` enables [universal newline](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode.